# Automatically input data into webpage and download the result

Tags: python, html

I am trying to automatically input values into this webpage
http://predict.habhub.org/
and download the resulting csv file that is created when you press the run prediction button.
I would like to be able to do this multiple times(90 different combinations of initial parameters), I can make the for loop fine, but am unable to enter this information into the website with code.

```
altitudes = [32000, 33000, 34000]
ascentRates = [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5]
descentRates = [11, 13, 15, 17, 19]


for altitude in altitudes:

    for ascent in ascentRates:

        for descent in descentRates:
            print(altitude)
            print(ascent)
            print(descent)
            print("")
```

This is probably really simple, however, since my programming knowledge is limited I don't really know where to start. I have tried to do this with python(urllib/requests) but am not getting anywhere. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: This website is using AJAX. You need to issue a call using `urllib2.urlopen` using the data that you need to input (`'http://predict.habhub.org/ajax.php?action=submitForm', 'launchsite=Churchill&lat=52.2135&lon=0.0964&initial_alt=0&hour=22&min=35&second=0&day=23&month=6&year=2017&ascent=5&burst=30000&drag=5&submit=Run+Prediction'). Then parse the response's json so you can get the UUID and use that UUID (after you make sure it's done computing) to download the CSV. You can use urllib to encode a dictionary into that query string.

Comment: Thanks  for the response! I am pretty sure you are giving me a really straight forward solution, but this is my first time programming in python, so I am little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognition goes to Jkm for solving my dilemma!

For anyone who has come across a similar problem here is my final code:

```
import requests
import json



#The date must be in the future for this to work!

launchSite = 'Other'  #Don't change this line
latitude = 39.0063
longitude = -104.8841
launchAltitude = 2212
launchHour = 15 #For colorado add 6hrs to local time(MDT)
launchMinute = 0
launchSecond = 0
launchDay = 24
launchMonth = 6 #this must be a number(ie June = 6)
launchYear = 2017
ascentRates = [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5]
burstAltitudes = [32000, 33000, 34000]
descentRates = [11, 13, 15, 17, 19]





for burstAltitude in burstAltitudes:

    for ascent in ascentRates:

        for descent in descentRates:
            print(burstAltitude)
            print(ascent)
            print(descent)
            print("")
            payload = {'launchsite': launchSite, 'lat': latitude, 'lon': longitude, 'initial_alt': launchAltitude, 'hour': launchHour,
                       'min': launchMinute, 'second': launchSecond, 'day': launchDay, 'month': launchMonth, 'year': launchYear, 'ascent': ascent,
                       'burst': burstAltitude, 'drag': descent, 'submit': 'Run+Prediction'}
            url = 'http://predict.habhub.org/ajax.php?action=submitForm'
            r = requests.post(url, payload)
            print(r.text)

            uuid = r.json()['uuid']

            csv_url = 'http://predict.habhub.org/preds/{}/flight_path.csv'.format(uuid)
            r = requests.get(csv_url)
            name = 'burst=' + str(burstAltitude) +' ascent=' + str(ascent) + ' descent=' + str(descent)
            with open('predicted_%s.csv' % name, 'w') as f:
                f.write(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `requests` module is the (arguably only) right choice for anything involving HTTP and Python.
In this case you need to "POST" (upload) your data to the server (see [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)).

Now you have to find out what kind of data gets "POSTed" where. Using, for instance, Chrome's Web Inspector, you can see that the following data gets posted to `http://predict.habhub.org/ajax.php?action=submitForm`:

`launchsite=Other&lat=52.2135&lon=0.0964&initial_alt=0&hour=21&min=48&second=0&day=23&month=6&year=2017&ascent=5&burst=30000&drag=5&submit=Run+Prediction`

You now have to create a payload dict that can be fed into requests.post(). In this dict, you can adjust the values to whatever you want to send to the server (note that the form uses different identifiers than your sample data: burst = altitude, drag = descentRate):

```
import requests
payload = {'launchsite': 'Other', 'lat': '52.2135', 'lon': '0.0964', 'initial_alt': '0', 'hour': '21', 'min': '48', 'second': '0', 'day': '23', 'month': '6', 'year': '2017', 'ascent': '5', 'burst': '30000', 'drag': '5', 'submit': 'Run+Prediction'}
url = 'http://predict.habhub.org/ajax.php?action=submitForm'
r = requests.post(url, payload)
```

Provided all goes well, you should have received some json data containing your uuid, which you can extract as follows:

```
uuid = r.json()['uuid']
```

Now you can download and store your csv data:

```
csv_url = 'http://predict.habhub.org/preds/{}/flight_path.csv'.format(uuid)
r = requests.get(csv_url)
with open('flight_path.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you soo much. I have been trying to get this to work for hours and I really appreciate the time you took to help!